# What is the subject of the verb [settle]? He waited until complete quiet settled on the assembly

Tags: subordinate-clauses, subjects

A sentence from dictionay [assembly: entry 2 in Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assembly)

> He waited until complete quiet settled on the assembly.

I guess

**complete** is an adjective and **quiet** ia an uncountable noun

What is the subject of the verb **settle**? quiet? or He?

What is the meaning of **settle** for that subject?

Comment: "Complete quiet settled on the assembly" is a clause with "complete quiet" as subject and "settled on the assembly" as the predicate VP. I suggest you use your dictionary to find the meaning of the verb "settle".

Comment: Yes,I look up the word **settle** in the same dictionay. It seems to me that ... like an argument or problem **settles**? [settle entry 1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/settle)

Comment: "settle" in this sense means: "To subside, calm down. Of the brain, mind, etc.: To become calm or composed." - from the OED.

Comment: @BillyKerr The [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/settle) has a close meaning of **settle**: to reach and remain at a certain _level_ or in a certain _state_.

Comment: @StatsCruncher Here's the link for the verb [settle](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00221031) in the OED (1982). Unfortunately the most recent entry is behind a paywall.  There's an interesting note to the entry which says "In many of the senses explained below, the verb frequently appears with a colouring derived from senses of different origin, so that the position of many of the examples is open to dispute." - so yeah, they are basically saying that it's difficult word to define precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant "core" sense of ***to settle*** is essentially *change from an active / dynamic state to a static unchanging state*. Typically, this sense occurs in, for example,...

> *Eventually the pandemonium settled and the meeting came to order*.

But in OP's cited context, the subject of the verb is *[complete] **quiet***, so that doesn't make a lot of sense ("quiet" is *already* "static"). In this case, we understand the verb as meaning ***become established***.

It's a metaphorical use of the literal sense ***settle = come down and remain***, such as might apply to falling snowflakes.

Comment: The aspect you mention is exactly what I was curious and confued about. Though Cambridge has a good explanation. I wonder if Collins and Oxford could provide exhaustive meaning of **settle**.

Comment: Like you say Falling snowflaked, [Collins Entry 8](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/settle) provides a similar example. A black dust settled on the walls.

Comment: Yeah - native speakers think nothing of things like *A **hush settled** on the crowd*, but I can see how learners might find it odd to speak of something that's already completely flat / lifeless / inactive becoming even more so as it "settles"..